# Getting error when printing json array in EJS variable on console

Tags: html, node.js, express, ejs

Guys I am using expressjs, ejs to develop an online shopping website.

Scenario
In order to display products {name, description, imageUrl} I am iterating with the help of ejs control-flow on the webpage.

I am sending an array that contains all the details about each product in JSON format. (from server)
on the client-side when I try to access this array of jsons I get the following error.

```
(index):266 Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
```

When I opened the sources tab in google chrome it, showed me this

[image]

At line number **266**. I believe that it is taking this as a string by wrapping the array in double quotes.?

Could anyone tell me what's going wrong with this code?

And by the way, is how I trying to print the array on **chrome console**

```
  <script>
    const data = JSON.parse("<%- products %>");
    console.log(data);
  </script>
```

where products are an array of jsons

Backend home route which is sending the JSON array is as follows

```
router.get("/", async (req, res) => {
  let catalogInformation = {};
  //getAllProducts returns array of json from the database
  const products = await getAllProducts();
  catalogInformation.products = products;
  userData = {
    email: null,
    username: null,
  };
  catalogInformation.userData = userData;
  if (req.session.userInformation != null || req.session.userInformation != undefined) {
    catalogInformation.userData = req.session.userInformation;
  } else {
    catalogInformation.userData = {
      email: null,
      username: null,
    };
  }
  // res.render("catalog", userData);
  res.render("catalog", catalogInformation);
  return;
});
```

`getAllProducts()` method

```
const getAllProducts = async () => {
  const Product = mongoose.model("product", productSchema);
  const allProducts = await Product.find();
  return allProducts;
};
```

Comment: Can you please provide the code on the backend?

Comment: It looks like the array is generated in the `getAllProducts()` function.  Are you able to provide the code for that function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use `JSON.parse`.  Just output the JSON directly:

```
var data = <%- products %>;
```

I wouldn't suggest making an AJAX call because you'd be handling 2 requests instead of 1.

Comment: But why is the output not wrapped in [ ]? though I am sending an array.

Comment: I don't know, I'd have to see the backend code to be able to help.

Comment: Hey, I just added the backed route. If this is not enough. I will share my git repo link here.

Comment: Yeah, I added the products method. Please take a look.

Comment: Nothing about the code looks like it wouldn't/shouldn't output the brackets.  Did the backquote work?  Are the brackets still not outputting with the updated code?

Comment: Oh, nono...It worked when I updated the code as you suggested. But the concept was a little unclear. That's why I asked you what could be the issue